# React Native - Objects are not valid as a react child

Tags: react-native

I am pulling some information from the Github api, using the fetch command in React Native.

I have a dashboard that is supposed to display the json info:

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> This is the dashboard </Text>
        <Text> {this.props.userInfo} </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
};
```

It's complaining and giving me this error:

ExceptionsManager.js:61 Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {login, id, avatar_url, gravatar_id, url, html_url, followers_url, following_url, gists_url, starred_url, subscriptions_url, organizations_url, repos_url, events_url, received_events_url, type, site_admin, name, company, blog, location, email, hireable, bio, public_repos, public_gists, followers, following, created_at, updated_at}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Text`.

Comment: For context, this seems to be related to the egghead.io React Native course, specifically lesson 6: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-06-react-native-passing-data-when-changing-routes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want something like this: https://rnplay.org/apps/YDWCxQ

The idea is to go through the props object you have, convert it to array and return the mapping wrapped in correct (`<Text>`) element:

```
return Object.entries(this.props.userInfo).map(([key, val], i) => {
  return <Text key={'key-'+ i}>{key +': '+ val}</Text>; 
});
```

Comment: The link is dead, as is the site it links to.